# runtime processes to a file in java

Tags: java

I want to get running processes of my system i.e (task manager) and save them in a file but the problem is i am getting the running processes but they are not written to a file
My code is

```
BufferedWriter out = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter("C:\\Users\\Zeeshan Nisar\\Desktop\\process.txt", true));

// Get process and make reader from that process
Process p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("tasklist.exe");
BufferedReader s = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(p.getInputStream()));

// While reading, print.
String input = null;
while ((input = s.readLine()) != null) {
    out.write(input);
    out.newLine();
}

out.close();
```

Comment: and what output do you get if you simply write to System.out?

Comment: Image Name           PID Session Name        Session#    Mem Usage

System Idle Process              0 Services            0             24 K
System                              4 Services                   0             304 K
@ScaryWombat

Comment: Can not see any problems with this code.  Any errors that are not being reported?

Comment: No Sir there aren't @ScaryWombat

Comment: How about file permissions for output file?

Comment: Is the file created and it is empty, or is the file not created at all? Did you try setting the path to a directory without a space in it?

Comment: I think the problem is probably that when you use `Runtime.getRuntime().exec(String[])`, you already executed it. Then, you're looking at something which has already been executed and therefore, get no information from it. Or, something's wrong with the BufferedReader. These are just hunches.

Answer (score 0):

Try this. I moved it to a PrintWriter (mostly because it is easier to use than a BufferedWriter, at least in my opinion) and moved the reading system into a Scanner (also because it is easier to use, in my opinion). I also moved the Runtime element into a ProcessBuilder and redirected the error stream into standard out.

```
// Make a PrintWriter to write the file
PrintWriter printer = new PrintWriter("process.txt");

// Make a process builder so that we can execute the file effectively
ProcessBuilder procBuilder = new ProcessBuilder();
procBuilder.command(new String[] { "your", "commands" });   // Set the execution target of the PB
procBuilder.redirectErrorStream(true);  // Make it slam the error data into the standard out data
Process p = procBuilder.start();    // Start

// Scan the process
Scanner scan = new Scanner(p.getInputStream());
while (scan.hasNextLine()) {
    printer.println(scan.nextLine());   // While it provides data, print to file
}

// Close everything to prevent leaks
scan.close();
printer.close();
```